# Generating a random index for an array

Tags: java

I know this for normal integers, but is there for such a thing as indices?

```
Random dice = new Random();
int n = dice.nextInt(6);
System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: what is a normal integer? what are indices?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. An array index ist just an int, so you could use those random numbers as array index without a problem.

Comment: `Dice` in your example is a variable and hence should be written lowercase according to the common Java style.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What do you mean? Array indices are normal numbers, so you can easily do

```
String names[] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" };
Random Dice = new Random(); 
int n = Dice.nextInt(6); 
System.out.println(names[n]);
```

Or do you mean a random Iterator class? Google is your friend here, [this](http://www.lockergnome.com/awarberg/2007/04/22/random-iterator-in-java/) is the first hit I get.

Answer (score 11):

To generate a random index for `someArray` you do

```
int index = new Random().nextInt(someArray.length);
```

`nextInt(n)` returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and `n` (exclusive) which is why `someArray.length` is given as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be:

```
int randomElement = yourArray[Math.random()*yourArray.length];
```

Math.random() generates a random number between 0 and 1. If you multiply that number by the length of your array, you will get an random index for the array.

For example:   If Math.random() generated .2 and your array had a length of 10, you would get an index of 2.

Comment: Don't do that. The Random class solves this already, and guarantees an 'even' distribution.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on my answer. This is how I have done it for years, so it's good to know there's another, better option out there.

Comment: Doesn't `Math.random` return `double`? While the array would expect index to be `int`?

Comment: @parsecer, yes. The snippet in this answer does not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility that worked for me in React js if you want to return the value of that index in an array.

```js
const myArray = [1,2,5,7,6,87,45,34,23,12]
        
        const rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
        
        console.log('value of the index', rand);
        console.log('index in the array',myArray.indexOf(rand));
```