# How to generate a random font in java?

Tags: java, random, fonts

I'm completely new to java and coding in general and I need to make a program display certain text using different fonts each time randomly.

Comment: what have u tried so far ?

Comment: Get a [list of all the fonts](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/swing-faq-list-fonts-current-platform/) available on the computer and pick one randomly.

Comment: Honestly nothing yet, I have no idea how it's done

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a console or in a gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question should be split into two parts. `How can I list all available font family names in Java?` and `How to pick a random index of an array?`. You should always try to split your problems into separate smaller sub-problems.

Here are the answers to both problems: [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023137/generating-a-random-index-for-an-array) and [B](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/swing-faq-list-fonts-current-platform/).

I made a neat function out of it which picks you the name of a random font family. If the language of the text that should be rendered is not English, replace `Locale.ENGLISH` with your language.

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

private static String pickRandomFontFamily() {
    String[] availableFonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames(Locale.ENGLISH);

    return availableFonts[RANDOM.nextInt(availableFonts.length)];
}
```

Comment: You can of course [omit the Locale entirely](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getAvailableFontFamilyNames()), in which case the font family names will be in the current locale, which is almost always desired behavior.

Comment: @VGR I'd not recommend this. When it comes to fonts, you should always be aware of what glyphs you want to render on the screen. For example, if the text is Arabic or Japanese and you omit the language parameter, there might be some problems on European/American machines.

Comment: Specifying a Locale will not change which glyphs each font can render.  The Locale argument applies to the *names* of the fonts.  For instance, if a font has both its English name and its Spanish name embedded in it, `new Locale("es")` will cause the Spanish name of the font to be returned.